# Convert list to string by using OOP

Tags: python, oop, arraylist

I'm trying to convert a list to one sequence string, by using a method in OOP. For example, I would like to convert **['Stack', 'over', 'flow', 3]** to **'Stackoverflow3'.**

When I tried doing that, the results were still returned as a list-

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(str(i) for i in self.array)


s_1 = ["Stack", "over", "flow", 3]
print(s_1.__str__())
```

I got this output - `['Stack', 'over', 'flow', 3]`

Could you please guide me on how to do it right?

Comment: WHERE do you create an instance of this new class that uses your fancy method? I just see you create a basic list ... and print that *hint hint*

Comment: beisde that : you are using a dunder method directly (which you should not do) - use `print(s_1)` (calls it implicitly)  or `print(str(s_1))` to do it excplicitly

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class defined:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(str(i) for i in self.array)


s_1 = NewClass(["Stack", "over", "flow", 3])
print(s_1)  # print 'automatically' uses __str__!
```

Out:

```
Stackoverflow3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class 'NewClass' before you pass the list argument.  Your code should look like this:  `

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, array):
      self.array = array

    def __str__(self):
      return "".join(str(i) for i in self.array)


 s_1 = NewClass(["Stack", "over", "flow", 3])
 print(s_1.__str__())`
```